# Only header loads once an item is added to the cart

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cart, php, configuration

Ever since moving our Magento store to a new server we have been having strange issues with the store.

Currently the store appears to work correctly but once an item is added to the cart all the pages break. The only part that loads is the header.

View the issue here by adding any item to the cart:
http://xpresselectrical.ie

There hasn't been any changes to the code base since moving to the new server so I must assume there is something different about this servers configuration.

I have enabled `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in `index.php` but no errors are shown.

Does anybody know what would cause this issue or how it can be resolved?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me. I added a product to the cart and everything is OK.

Comment: Not for me, only header loaded on add to cart. (Firefox/IE 11) Have you checked your system.log and exception.log file in /var/log?

Comment: Ah...I found one product that breaks the page. The page rendering stops at the cart header with `<img scr="`. Check the template that is rendering the minicart and see if there is a problem with the image display.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I have discovered that our new server does not have the GD Library extension installed! This would probably explain why the page rendering stops at the img tag. I am currently updating our Apache configuration and installing GD. Hopefully that will solve the issue.

Comment: @Marius, please post it as an answer so topic starter can accept it.

Comment: I will as soon as I can confirm it works :) Will take a few minutes for Apache to rebuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page rendering stops at the cart header with `<img src="`. Check the template that is rendering the minicart and see if there is a problem with the image display.

---

<sub>Added as an answer at @Tim's suggestion</sub>

Comment: Decided to do a few other bits since the website was down anyway. That seems to have solved our problem anyway, pages are loading properly and everything looks good. Thanks.